# Database folder on development mode

Tags: arangodb

On arangodb's documentation it is suggested to use a different folder to databases during development phase (/tmp/fancy_db). I try to use this but I get errors saying that no database exists... How can I create databases on this temporary folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arangod will not create any folder for you, you have to give it an existing folder on your system.

```
/tmp/fancy_db
```

is just a suggestion you can use any folder at any location on your machine.
However to create a folder in /tmp on a unix system open a terminal and enter:

```
bash> mkdir /tmp/fancy_db
```

On a windows system (as far as i know) \tmp is not available, you can use

```
C:\tmp\fancy_db
```

instead (create it with Explorer)